# install python version using ubuntu 22.04 image

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu

I was using python official images for getting specific python version.

But due to some other requirements, i want to use ubuntu 22.04 image

How to install specific python version in unbuntu image

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# how to install specific python version as we get from official image
#install python 3.10.10
```

Answer (score 1):

The package manager for Ubuntu is `apt`. In order to install Python to a Ubuntu-based image during Docker build, use the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y python3.6 # or 3.7, or whichever version you prefer

...
```